# Get the entire row/rows of a cell with the maximum value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to find the row with the maximum `product_count`.
This is the SQL that I have tried but it doesn't give the correct result:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(product_count)
GROUP BY product_id
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(product_count) as max_count
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) as product_count
    FROM wp_stvp_voting_data
    GROUP BY product_id
) as T1
GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option is to use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS product_count
FROM wp_stvp_voting_data
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you needed to cater to the possibility that there might be more than one record tied for the maximum product count, and you wanted to return all ties, then we could try using a subquery:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS product_count
FROM wp_stvp_voting_data
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(product_id) = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
                               SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                               FROM yourTable
                               GROUP BY product_id
                           ) t)
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we would be able to take advantage of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT product_id, product_count
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS product_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY product_id
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` if you want all ties for first place.

Comment: thanks! I have a question, my table has a subquery. Using the second method you gave, if I replace the `yourTable` with `(SELECT....) as T1`, how can I use `T1` on the 3rd line after `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the actual query.  I won't speculate here in comments.

Comment: I have added the query after the EDIT section in the question